# MySQL Query Cache vs Custom Caching Function

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I was experiencing some problems with duplicate queries slowing down rendering a HTML table (very similar select queries inside a while loop). So I created some simple caching functions (php):

- `check_cache()`
- `write_cache()`
- `return_cache()`

These functions prevent the server from asking anything from the database.
**Which sped things up quite a lot!**

Later I read that MySQL caches SELECT statements:

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again.

**Why does this increase performance if MySQL is already doing this?**

Comment: It's possibly more a case of MySQL **can** cache SELECT queries if it's configured to do so; your query cache limit might be too low, it might not be able to use the cache because of the way the query is written ... and so on. It might also be worth looking at Memcached or Redis.

Comment: @CD001 Ok, so if MySQL was working as expected these functions would have no affect on performance? (I'd much rather this kind of thing was handled internally)

Comment: In theory... but your PHP script still contacts the database server with MySQL caching so if there's a bottleneck there (or extremely heavy load) you could still hit an issue. If your system relies on filecaching you're moving the bottleneck from the database server to the filesystem... generally speaking filesystem reads are slower than database reads (even though the database uses the filesystem for storage) ... but not always :) With something like Memcached or Redis the results are stored in system memory - retrieval is really fast.

Comment: @CD001 I think this explains it: `query_cache_size 0` doh! My local server is set to `16777216` which is probably why I got confused, that's what I'm going to blame it on anyway, one day I'll stop looking stupid on this site ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible issues

1) If your application updates tables frequently, then the query cache will be constantly purged and you won't get any benefit from this.

2)The query cache is not supported for partitioned tables.

3)The query cache does not work in an environment where you have multiple mysqld servers updating the same MyISAM tables.

4)The SELECT statements should be identical.